# Run a function(private) when Swing Application Starts

Tags: java, swing, oop, netbeans

I am currently making a program using an RFID to take input and show its information using a Java Swing Interface.

My problem here is that I created a function that continuously check if there is an input in the RFID and shows it using Swing, but I need to run that function when the application starts.

*I tried using public functions but it can't use `jlabel.setText` and other function because it is being run on static.

I consider adding a start button just to make the wheels turn but I prefer not to use any buttons so that the interface is clean.

```
package com.domain.test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class SerialReader implements Runnable {

    InputStream in;

    public SerialReader(InputStream in) {
        this.in = in;
    }

    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        String dataHolder;
        String IDnumber = new String();
        int incomingData = -1;
        int ctr = 0;
        try {

            while ((incomingData = this.in.read(buffer)) > -1) {
                dataHolder = new String(buffer, 0, incomingData);

                if (incomingData >= 1) {


                    ctr++;

                    IDnumber = IDnumber + dataHolder;
                    if (IDnumber.length()==14) {

                        System.out.println(IDnumber);
                        log display = new log();
                        display.setLabel(IDnumber.substring(1, IDnumber.length() - 1));
                        IDnumber = new String();
                        ctr = 0;

                    }

                } 

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

What I need to do is pass the data which is being submitted to this function then pass it to this Swing function(setText).

```
 public void setLabel(String studNum){
   sNum = studNum;
   jName.setText(sNum);
}
```

The problem is that I can pass the data but I cant use it to display on my interface. That is why I'm asking on how to create a function(can communicate with Swing) that will run when the application starts.

Also if you can give me another way on how I can pass the data to my Swing.

Comment: Without the actual code, this question can not be answered... Put it on your question by useing the edit button please.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement polling to look for the input

From http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html

> A Swing timer (an instance of
> `javax.swing.Timer`) fires one or more
> action events after a specified delay.
> Don't confuse Swing timers with the
> general-purpose timer facility that
> was added to the java.util package in
> release 1.3. This page describes only
> Swing timers.
>
> In general, we recommend
> using Swing timers rather than
> general-purpose timers for GUI-related
> tasks because Swing timers all share
> the same, pre-existing timer thread
> and the GUI-related task automatically
> executes on the event-dispatch thread.
> However, you might use a
> general-purpose timer if you don't
> plan on touching the GUI from the
> timer, or need to perform lengthy
> processing.

Answer (score 2):

You need a thread, timer, or executor service to start and check for that RFID feed.

Why can't you just instantiate and start the thread when you create the app?  I see no need for a button.

I wouldn't do this operation on the Swing thread.  The result will be rendered in the UI, but the operation isn't truly a Swing problem.

Answer (score 0):

> First of all you need a seperate thread for rendering the GUI to show
>   IDNumber so that your Reader thread is not blocked when GUI is
>   rendering the IDNumber.

> Second, you need the concurrent display of IDNumber and reading the
>   messages from input Stream.

You can achieve both above said requirements by using `SwingWorker` API provided by `Swing.`

> And finally to make sure that Reader starts running only after the GUI
>   (display) starts, you need `volatile` keyword so that JVM doesnot
>   change the sequence of code in pretext of optimizing the codes while
>   execution.

Here I am posting a code snippet to achieve all these. I hope it might be of your help.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.List;
class SerialReader extends SwingWorker<Void,String>
{
    Log display ;
    String messages[] =     {
                    "Java supports OOPS!!",
                    "JRE is the bundle of JVM and java Class liberary",
                    "JVM executes the java bytecode.",
                    "JIT converts code at runtime prior to executing it natively",
                    "Stay here I'll be back after reading more about java!!!! :)"
                };
    private SerialReader(){}//To avoid construction of object without parameter
    public SerialReader(Log display)
    {   
        this.display = display;
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground()
    {
        try
        {
            //Reading Messages one by one till the end
            for(int i=0;i<messages.length;i++)
            {
                String message = messages[i];
                publish(message);
                Thread.sleep(600);//I have added this much delay in compensation to the time 
                        //that would be taken when u are formating data from inputstream.
            }           //You must sleep the Thread for at least 1 ms so that change in 
                        //display could be visualized.
        }catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
        finally
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<String> chunks)
    {
        for(String msg: chunks)
        {
            display.setLabel(msg);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void done()
    {}
}
class Log extends JFrame
{
    private JLabel label = new JLabel("");
    public Log()
    {
        super("Display");
    }
    public void prepareAndDisplay()
    {
        getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        getContentPane().add(label);    
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(400,100);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public void setLabel(final String value)
    {
        label.setText(value);
    }
}
public class MainClass 
{
    private static volatile Log log;
    private static volatile SerialReader reader;
    public static void main(String st[])
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                log = new Log();
                log.prepareAndDisplay();
                log.setLabel("Display is ready Please Wait for incoming message...");
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(100);//Delayed the start of Reader by 100 ms
                }catch(Exception ex){}
                reader = new SerialReader(log);
                reader.execute();
            }       
        });                                 
    }
}
```

To know more about `SwingWorker` API Click [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html). To know about how to use `SwingWorker` click [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) .